# If $g$ is a continuous function and $F(x) = x^3+ g(x)$, then $F$ is also continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I'm stuck with a problem, I'm not sure how to do solve it or what to do to make sense of it. It goes like this:

$g(x)$ is a function that is continuous within $\mathbb{R}$ and $F(x) = x^3+ g(x)$

a. Explain why $F$ is continuous within $\mathbb{R}$;

b. Show that $c ∈ [−1, 1]$ such that $g(c) = -c^3$

I don't know how to go about showing how $f$ is continuous, normally what I would would do with these is calculating the function's value with the value they would ask for continuity, but in here they're asking for $\mathbb{R}$ and I'm not sure what to do when that comes up.

Comment: Could you edit your Part(b)? I don't understand the claim there.

Comment: "within R" just means that it is continuous at all real values.

Comment: Also by "$F$ is continuous within $R$", did you mean $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers?

Comment: HINT for part a: $\lim_{x \to a}(x^3+g(x))=\lim_{x \to a}(x^3)+\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$

Comment: That's what part b says, I copied it exactly the way it was I'm assuming that what it is really asking there is to prove that the function has a solution within that interval.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition of continuity:

$f(x)$ is *continuous* at $c$ iff $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c} f(c)=f(c)$

As Paul showed in the comments:

Part A)

$\lim_{x \to a} F(x)=\lim_{x \to a}(x^3+g(x))=\lim_{x \to a}(x^3)+\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = a^3+g(a)=F(a) \;\; \forall a\in \mathbb{R}$

Part B) not sure what's going on with that question.

Comment: I think what they meant to say with that part was to show that $-c^3$ is a solution to that function found at that interval. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

For part b), basically, you need to show that there exists at least one   $c \in [-1,1]$, such that $F(c)=0$. However, $F(x)$ could be a constant function! (e.g. $F(x)=4$, in case $g(x)=-x^3+4$, which is continuous). I guess something is missing! I would say that you are supposed to use *intermediate value theorem* or *Bolzano's theorem.*